# Arquivo para dicionário

Tags: python-3.x, arquivo, dicionário

Eu estou tentando transformar um arquivo em dicionário mas está dando o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\taynan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projeto
>   CRUD\Interface.py", line 46, in 
>       consultarProfessor(cpfP, arqProfessores)   File "C:\Users\taynan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projeto
>   CRUD\ModuloDeFuncoes.py", line 38, in consultarProfessor
>       key, val = line[:-1].split() ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Alguem consegue identificar onde está o erro? Pq eu não to sabendo :/

Arquivo:

```
{'Nome': 'd', 'Cpf': '33', 'Departamento': 'a'}
{'Nome': 'f', 'Cpf': '22', 'Departamento': 'g'}
{'Nome': 'a', 'Cpf': '13', 'Departamento': 'b'}
{'Nome': 'x', 'Cpf': '24', 'Departamento': 'd'}
```

Aqui uma parte do código, pois é muito grande:

```
def consultarProfessor(cpf, arquivoEspecifico):
arquivo = lerArquivo(arquivoEspecifico)
for linha in arquivo:
    linha = linha.replace('"',"")
    chave, valor = linha[:-1].split()
    dicProfessores[chave] = valor
if cpf in dicProfessores.values():
    dicProfessor = dicProfessores[cpf]
    arquivo.close()                                            #definindo uma variavel para a chave do dicionario de professores
    print(dicProfessores)
else:
    print("Este professor não é funcionário desta faculdade.")
```

Obs. Já tentei usar `dicProfessores = eval(linha[-1])`, mas estava dando muitos erros.

```
#Edit: Consegui criar o dicionário, mas ele está saindo todo errado:
def file_to_dict(arquivoEspecifico):
dic = {}
arquivo = lerArquivo(arquivoEspecifico)
for linha in arquivo:
    linha = linha.replace('"',"")
    valor = linha[:-1].split()
    chave = linha[:-1].split()
    for v in valor:
        v = v.replace(",","")
        v = v.replace("{","")
        v = v.replace("}","")
        v = v.replace(":","")
        v = v.replace("'","")
        for c in chave:
            c = c.replace(",","")
            c = c.replace("{","")
            c = c.replace("}","")
            c = c.replace(":","")
            c = c.replace("'","")
            dic[c] = v
print(dic)
return dic
```

Aqui como ele está saindo:

```
{'Nome': 'g', 'd': 'a', 'Cpf': 'g', '33': 'a', 'Departamento': 'g', 'a': 'a', 'f': 'g', '22': 'g', 'g': 'g'}
```

Comment: Digite o cpf do professor: 33
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taynan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projeto CRUD\Interface.py", line 46, in <module>
    consultarProfessor(cpfP, arqProfessores)
  File "C:\Users\taynan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projeto CRUD\ModuloDeFuncoes.py", line 38, in consultarProfessor
    key, val = print(line[:-1].split())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Ta dizendo que a lista ta fazia, o erro ta no split eu acho :/

Answer (score 1):

O módulo **[json](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html)** pode facilitar a construção da sua função. A função *loads()* transforma str em dict com a necessidade de seguir apenas algumas regras pré-estabelecidas. No seu caso, as únicas coisas que você terá que lidar são as aspas simples e as quebras de linha. Mas essas questões podem ser corrigidas com o *.replace()* que você já está usando.

Como seu código não está com indentação, não entendi se seu intuito é fazer um dicionário com todos os dados, e só depois fazer a consulta, ou se você quer fazer a consulta linha a linha.

Se for apenas fazer a consulta linha a linha, você pode fazer assim:

```
import json

def consultarProfessor(cpf, arquivoEspecifico):
    with open(arquivoEspecifico, "r") as arquivo:
        for li in arquivo:
            li = li.replace("'", "\"")
            li = li.replace("/n", "")
            li = json.loads(li)   # <-- Transforma str em dict
            if str(cpf) == li["Cpf"]:
                return li
        return "Não encontrado"

file = "lista.txt"
cpf_consult = 24

print(consultarProfessor(cpf_consult, file))
```

Comment: Nossa, não sei nem como te agradecer, faziam semanas que eu estava tentando transformar o arquivo em dicionário bonitinho e não estava conseguindo. Se eu ganhar os 3 pontos nesse projeto eu vou dedicar a você kkkkkkk
E obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar :D

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o seu erro está na linha

```
chave, valor = linha[:-1].split()
```

essa atribuição não é permitida para esse determinado caso
Bom eu testei as atribuições em separado e deu certo dessa forma

```
chave = linha[:-1].split()
valor = linha[:-1].split()
```

conforme mostrado no prompt
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, só isso não resolve seu problema... dito isso fiz essa implementação funcional

```
# Esse código serve se seguir esse modelo  
# Esse modelo foi usado como exemplo -> suponha que linha = "{'Nome': 'd', 'Cpf': '33', 'Departamento': 'a'}" 
dict = {}
for linha in arquivo:
    linha = linha.replace("'", "")

    b = linha.split(',')

    for i in b:
        c  = i.split(':')
        c[0] = c[0].replace("{","")
        c[0] = c[0].replace("}","")
        c[0] = c[0].replace(":","")
        c[1] = c[1].replace("{","")
        c[1] = c[1].replace("}","")
        c[1] = c[1].replace(":","")
        dict[c[0]] = c[1]
print dict
```

O código resulta em um dicionário com chaves e valores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Po mano vlw mesmo, não fazia idéia disso, mas agora ta dando esse erro:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taynan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projeto CRUD\Interface.py", line 46, in <module>
    consultarProfessor(cpfP, arqProfessores)
  File "C:\Users\taynan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projeto CRUD\ModuloDeFuncoes.py", line 40, in consultarProfessor
    dicProfessores[key] = val
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Sò que eu coloquei assim também:
   dicProfessores[chave] = valor

Comment: então vê essa resolução que eu editei agora na resposta.

Comment: Gerou um dicionário com as informações

Comment: Obrigado amigo, eu fiz uma função pra transformar arquivo em dicionário usando seu código, mas eu já tentei diversas formas de corrigir o seu código, mas ele continua dando esse erro: 


  File "C:\Users\taynan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projeto CRUD\ModuloDeFuncoes.py", line 54, in consultarProfessor
    dicProfessores = file_to_dict(arquivoEspecifico)
  File "C:\Users\taynan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projeto CRUD\ModuloDeFuncoes.py", line 35, in file_to_dict
    c[1] = c[1].replace("{","")
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: pelos testes que eu fiz ele não está armazenando os valores do dicionário, que no caso seria o c[1]

Comment: Consegui criar o dicionário, está la na edição do post